# SQL server query with if statement in batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a two tables table1 and table2 and both containing ID column. I want to find max(ID) of table1 and max(ID) of table2 and if both max IDs are same, I will call a C# program using .exe.

```
Create table table1(ID int not null,
 CONSTRAINT [pkid1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
));
Create table table2(ID int not null,
 CONSTRAINT [pkid2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
));


@ECHO ON
echo running batch file 
if ((select max(ID) from table1)=(select max(ID) from table2)) call D:\atest\bin\debug\atest.exe
```

Now how can I include this if statement in a batch file?
Thanks

MR

Comment: Gee this looks eerily familiar to another post on SSC. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1607551-391-1.aspx

Comment: My friend Tom Thomson answered there with this: "((select max(ID) from table1)=(select max(ID) from table2)) exec xp_cmdshell c#program ;". Based on your question that sure looks like the answer to me.